# Minification error with some Angular modalInstance.opened method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, gulp-uglify

I have written a set of gulp commands to minify JS code. It works fine unless I include following code segment on a particular JS file.

```
//============================== Ledger Card Modal =================================== //KR: Check
    vm.ledgerCardWindowOption = function (matterReferenceNo) {
        var busy = busyIndicatorService.setAsBusy('CompanyName.main');
        vm.ledgerCardGlyphicon = true;
        $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
            scope: $scope,
            templateUrl: 'app/ledgerCard/ledgerCardView.html',
            backdrop: 'static',
            controller: 'ledgerCardController as vm',
            windowClass: 'ledgercard-modal-window',
            resolve: {
                ledgerCardModal: function () {
                    var data = { matterReferenceNo: matterReferenceNo, formType: "Modal" };
                    return data;
                }
            }
        });
        $scope.modalInstance.opened.then(() => busy.resolve(), () => busy.resolve()); // This is the bad line
    };
    //============================== Ledger Card Modal End ===================================
    //==============================auto height fix===================================
```

**Error message:**

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\dev.net14\DevelopmentPhase2\CompanyName.WebMain\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:30:4), <anonymous>:1533:18)
    at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\dev.net14\DevelopmentPhase2\CompanyName.WebMain\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:30:4), <anonymous>:1541:11)
    at croak (eval at <anonymous> (C:\dev.net14\DevelopmentPhase2\CompanyName.WebMain\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:30:4), <anonymous>:2088:9)
    at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\dev.net14\DevelopmentPhase2\CompanyName.WebMain\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:30:4), <anonymous>:2096:9)
    at unexpected (eval at <anonymous> (C:\dev.net14\DevelopmentPhase2\CompanyName.WebMain\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:30:4), <anonymous>:2102:9)
    at expr_atom (eval at <anonymous> (C:\dev.net14\DevelopmentPhase2\CompanyName.WebMain\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:30:4), <anonymous>:2617:13)
    at maybe_unary (eval at <anonymous> (C:\dev.net14\DevelopmentPhase2\CompanyName.WebMain\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:30:4), <anonymous>:2791:19)
    at expr_ops (eval at <anonymous> (C:\dev.net14\DevelopmentPhase2\CompanyName.WebMain\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:30:4), <anonymous>:2826:24)
    at maybe_conditional (eval at <anonymous> (C:\dev.net14\DevelopmentPhase2\CompanyName.WebMain\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:30:4), <anonymous>:2831:20)
    at maybe_assign (eval at <anonymous> (C:\dev.net14\DevelopmentPhase2\CompanyName.WebMain\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:30:4), <anonymous>:2855:20)
```

I have pointed out the bad line on above code, but I can not figure out what is wrong there. Could anyone please explain me?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ES6` features, you need to use a `transpilier` to convert those code in `ES5`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel

Before you `uglify`, convert the `ES2015` to `ES5`.